# Association is in database, but can't be retrieved via DAL. Will retrieve empty array of associations

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am following the advanced developer tutorial (https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/indepth-guide-bundle).

Currently I'm at step 7, and according to the tutorial what I've made so far should work.

But it doesn't.

In the database it shows the association, but I can't retrieve them from the repository.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information?
Like are you trying to load the data from the php backend stack or from the vue.js admin stack?
What's the sample code that you use and what exactly is not working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, turns out I switched up two parameters by accident. When I set them correctly it worked as it should.

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Swag\BundleExample\Core\Content\Product;

use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityExtension;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\Inherited;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\ManyToManyAssociationField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\FieldCollection;
use Swag\BundleExample\Core\Content\Bundle\Aggregate\BundleProduct\BundleProductDefinition;
use Swag\BundleExample\Core\Content\Bundle\BundleDefinition;

class ProductExtension extends EntityExtension
{
    public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
    {
        $collection->add(
            (new ManyToManyAssociationField(
                'bundles', 
                BundleDefinition::class,
                BundleProductDefinition::class, 
                'product_id', 
                'bundle_id'
            ))->addFlags(new Inherited())
        );
    }

    public function getDefinitionClass(): string
    {
        return ProductDefinition::class;
    }
}
```

I'm talking about the 'product_id' and 'bundle_id'. In my case I had the 'product_id' as the last parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the association to the Criteria.

`$criteria->addAssociation("name_of_association")`
Without it, the associations come as null.

Comment: This also works. But in my case I formed the association wrongly.